# Xslt move node to parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml structure:

```
<root>
 <a>
   <b>
     <c>
       <c1>123</c1>
       <c2>abc</c2>
     </c>
     <d/>
     <e/>
     <f/>
   </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

How do I remove `<b>` but preserve `<c>` and its child nodes under a, like

```
<root>
 <a>
   <c>
     <c1>123</c1>
     <c2>abc</c2>
   </c>
 </a>
</root>
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Do you want to preserve `<c>` and remove all other nodes (as shown in your example output)? And what about the children of the other nodes?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm sorry I made an error while typing the question, I've updated it now

Comment: Yes, but you still **say** "remove `<b>`" and **show** "remove everything but `<c>`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an identity transform with an exception. This extra template

```
<xsl:template match="a/*[not(self::c)]">
```

matches an element if it is a child of `a`, but not named "c". If this is the case, the element is simply ignored, together with all its content.

**EDIT**: You have changed the requirement, I have changed the code and output. Now, the `b` element is *traversed* and all child elements of `b` are ignored, except for `c`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b/*[not(self::c)]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

```
<root>
 <a>
   <b>
     <c>
       <c1>123</c1>
       <c2>abc</c2>
     </c>
     <d/>
     <e/>
     <f/>
   </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

**XMl Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a>
      <c>
         <c1>123</c1>
         <c2>abc</c2>
      </c>
   </a>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I had made an error while typing the question, it's slightly different now, but now I know to how to apply the same idea, thanks!

Comment: Interesting, match="b/*[not(self::c)]" does not match comments, is it possible match comments i.e to remove them?

Comment: @Rnet Yes, that's possible. Would you like to remove comments in the whole document? If you want to get rid of the comments inside `b`, use: `match="b/node()[not(self::c)]" `. This also removes processing-instructions.

Comment: Not the whole document, only from the tag that's removed, b

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want to do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="c"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```